# ruby for each key/value pair in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I have a bit of a problem with MongoDB in that it returns hashes with the keys in double quotes and integers as floats all the time, has this been a problem for anyone else?

for examples after a map reducing or grouping, say I have a bunch of hashes which look like this:

```
{"unknown"=>54.0, "pedestrians"=>572.0, "vehicles"=>1045.0}
```

But what I really want is:

```
{ unknown: 54, pedestrians: 572, vehicles: 1045 }
```

Any ideas on how I can easily convert it?

Comment: Is something like this helpful? See symbolize_keys: http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/Keys.html#M000244

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could do:

```
original = {"unknown"=>54.0, "pedestrians"=>572.0, "vehicles"=>1045.0}
converted = Hash[ original.map { |key, value| [key.to_sym, value.to_i] } ]
```

Or if you're using Rails, you could make it a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` and just convert the values:

```
original = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(original)
original.each { |key, value| original[key] = value.to_i }
```

Comment: What if the value is a String or actually does have a fraction?

Comment: @DigitalRoss Well, this answer presumes, as the OP states, that the original hash is always `String => Float`. If the types are something else it won't work - but that's not what was asked.

Comment: @TylerBrock Thanks! Although I edited out the version that used `tap` as I decided it was neater to just use `map` and convert back to a `Hash`.

Answer (score 3):

#### Trust Integral FP Values

In order to handle all possible key types correctly, if you are going to convert it I would suggest something like:

```
h = {:a => 54.0, :b => 572.0, :c => 1045.0, :d => 'test', :e => 1.23 }
p(h.merge(h) do |k, v|
  v = v.to_i if v.is_a?(Float) && v.to_i == v
  v
end)
```

The above code will convert Float values in a hash that are actually integral to Integer.

But you actually don't need to do this at all. While it's common to distrust the floating point formats, it turns out that they do represent integral values exactly.

You can trust that any value that was an integer in the database will compare exactly with integer constants (including 0) and that you will *not* see any rounding artifacts.

You *will* notice a difference, of course, if you divide a float by something other than a factor.